# random_shuffle not allowing me to pass it a seed

Tags: c++, random, vector, shuffle, random-seed

so I have a vector of cards and I'm trying to shuffle it using the random_shuffle method, but it's not shuffling them by only passing it the first and last item. So I know there's a third parameter which is a custom seed, the thing it, random_shuffle says it doesn't find any functions overloaded with these parameters (Or something like that - my program's in spanish)

Basically, I have two vectors, enemyCards and playerCards, both have a size of 5.

```
random_shuffle(enemyCards.begin(), enemyCards.end());
random_shuffle(playerCards.begin(), playerCards.end());
```

This compiles but is not working, while

```
int myrandom (int i)    { return std::rand()%i;}

random_shuffle(enemyCards.begin(), enemyCards.end(), myrandom);
random_shuffle(playerCards.begin(), playerCards.end(), myrandom);
```

doesn't even compile.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have a srand() at the beginning and other working rand() in the code, so the that should be working fine, it's just the random_shuffle that does not.

This is what the compiler says when using the myrandom method:

```
Error   11  error C3867: 'comgrid::Game::myrandom': function call missing argument list; use '&comgrid::Game::myrandom' to create a pointer to member
Error   12  error C2780: 'void _STL::random_shuffle(_RandomAccessIter,_RandomAccessIter)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
```

Which is strange, because it's really 1:1 as the example on cplusplus.

Comment: Do you get any kind of compile error? Like a type error?

Comment: [See](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the criteria for function object for `std::random_shuffle`

Comment: I'm just installing an english version of VS2012 real quick, then I'll post the compiler errors

Comment: Alright, I added them to my post.

Comment: You didn't make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), so [I made one for you and it works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a39f06dc3356eed9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `myrandom` a static member function of your `Game` class.

Comment: Alright, making it static makes the program compile, but it doesn't shuffle the vectors

Comment: Are the begin and end methods of enemyCards and playerCards custom ones? Or do they come directly from STL containers?

Comment: Those are the begin() and end() methods of a vector

Comment: Do you happen to have a custom swap function for the Card class used in your vectors?

Comment: No, there isn't any that could interfere

Comment: So, I actually found the problem. It DOES shuffle them, but the way I render them, it still shows them in the same order, that's why it didn't seem to work. Anyway, the main problem was fixed by adding the static to the function

Answer (score 1):

One does not pass a seed to [`random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle): the optional third argument is a function object that must return a random integer in [0,n) when passed `n` as an argument. The following SSCCE demonstrates the use of `random_shuffle` (and the "better" C++11 variant `shuffle`) for your 5 element vectors ([Live code at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f4241e004017846)):

```
void dump_one(const char* name, vector<int> const& v) {
    cout << name << ": {" << v[0];
    for (auto i = size_t{1}; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        cout << ',' << v[i];
    }
    cout << "}\n";
}

int myrandom(int i) { return rand() % i; }

int main() {
    srand(random_device{}());
    auto playerCards = vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
    auto enemyCards  = vector<int>{6,7,8,9,10};

    // Variant 1: use std::rand
    random_shuffle(begin(playerCards), end(playerCards));
    random_shuffle(begin(enemyCards), end(enemyCards));
    dump_one("player", playerCards);
    dump_one("enemy", enemyCards);

    // Variant 2: use functor
    random_shuffle(begin(playerCards), end(playerCards), myrandom);
    random_shuffle(begin(enemyCards), end(enemyCards), myrandom);
    dump_one("player", playerCards);
    dump_one("enemy", enemyCards);

    // C++11: Use shuffle instead of random_shuffle
    auto engine = mt19937_64{random_device{}()};
    shuffle(begin(playerCards), end(playerCards), engine);
    shuffle(begin(enemyCards), end(enemyCards), engine);
    dump_one("player", playerCards);
    dump_one("enemy", enemyCards);
}
```

The techniques that you say "don't work" are working correctly, so the problem with your program is not in the things you are describing to us.